# Is it mandatory to finalize dvd while creating bootable dvd?

Tags: bootable-media, dvd-burning

Since recent versions of ubuntu (12.10,13....) exceeds 700 MB I'm forced to use DVD instead of CD. But the size of ubuntu 12.10 is just 750 MB. still 3.5 GB of DVD will be wasted. So I'm wondering whether unchecking finalize disk option will make DVD non-bootable or can I still create bootable DVD by not finalizing it ? So that later I can store some related softwares or any other data I want.

I'm using Windows 8.1 enterprise evaluation OS

BurnAware to burn disk.

Thank you

Comment: When I burned an ISO image recently, my DVD burner program asked if I wanted re-writable capability. Is it possible to partition a DVD and put the bootable image in the first partition and use the second partition as backup storage (the ISO image will become outdated at some point)?

Comment: Even I have no idea. My question is almost similar to your doubt.

Comment: @LDC3 I tried it myself to create bootable Ubuntu 12.10 DVD without finalizing disk. And it is working fine. But don't know whether I can add another bootable OS to create dual boot. But I'm sure that the disk can be used to store data.